# How to use Spring Boot BOM, instead of parent?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-bom

I need to use `BOM`s in my project, so simplify the task of managing dependencies. This is the requirement, I cannot pivot at this stage.

I removed parent spring-boot and added AWS, Spring Boot and Junit5 as `BOM`s. The issue is, even though I have them, dependencies aren't downloaded correctly. Am I missing some plugins or I am doing something else wrong?

I have tried:

- Run code without BOMs
- Research BOM usage
- Run project with parent of Spring Boot
- Research similar projects on GitHub

All of the above worked correctly. The issues I am getting after adding BOMs are:

```
package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
package org.mockito does not exist
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class ExtendWith
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom-experiments</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.7.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <aws-sdk.version>2.18.16</aws-sdk.version>
        <mockito-inline.version>4.8.0</mockito-inline.version>
        <org.springframework.boot.version>2.7.5</org.springframework.boot.version>
        <org.springframework.version>5.3.24</org.springframework.version>

        <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <junit-jupiter-params.version>${junit-jupiter.version}</junit-jupiter-params.version>
        <kubernetes-maven-plugin.version>1.9.0</kubernetes-maven-plugin.version>

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <mockito.version>4.9.0</mockito.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${aws-sdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Secret managers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ssm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>bom-experiments</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Am I understanding BOM concept wrong? Why are there no dependencies, even though they are declared in pom.xml? How can I run this code without parent but with BOM?

Comment: It looks like I can change packaging from `jar` to `pom`: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom

How do I work with `pom` afterward? As far as I see, change of packaging doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had, was related to a misconfiguration in `pom.xml`

Instead of

```
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
```

I have to use

```
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main</sourceDirectory>
```

This said, it is possible to package differently from `pom` packaging, so I can use `jar` or other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the BOM via *dependencyManagement* and scope *import* copies their *dependencyManagement* configuration  into your current *dependencyManagement*, as you would have written these *dependencyManagement* configuration.

The section *dependencyManagement* should only be used within POM of packaging *pom*. The resulting *pom* artefact could be used as parent of other POM.

Therefore you should not use BOM without parent.

Have a closer look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html